# composer require <module_name>:<version> 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4, composer

Hello i'm trying to install a plugin with composer in Magento 2.4.4
but how can i fix following error? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Hi, Please run this command and try it - composer require iubenda/module-cookiesolution:*

Comment: thanks i tried but got the same error..

Answer (score 0):

As per the screenshot it requires phpseclib

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib

composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~3.0